# Preventing bell/ding in a PrototypeJS event handler

Tags: internet-explorer, prototypejs, dom-events

How do I translate the following to instead use PrototypeJS Event.observe?

`<input type="text" ....  onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;">`

The purpose being to prevent the ding which in some cases should not play (in IE9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've quoted would look like this using Prototype's event stuff:

```
var input = /* ...get the `input` element, how will depend on your structure... */;
input.observe('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.stop();
    }
});
```

[`Event#stop`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/prototype/stop/) does two things: It prevents the default action, if any, and it stops the event bubbling. If you just want to prevent the default action but not bubbling, use [`Event#preventDefault`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) instead (Prototype will make sure it's there, even on browsers that leave it off); if you just want to stop bubbling but not prevent the default action, use [`Event#stopPropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation) instead (again, Prototype will make sure it's there).

---

In terms of finding the `input` element: If it has an `id`, that's easy:

```
var input = $('theId');
```

Alternately, you can find it by where it is, or by its other attributes, using [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/), which offers fairly powerful selectors (most of CSS3).

Comment: While the handler does fire when pressing enter, IE9 still dings

Comment: @c0dem4gnetic: I'm afraid I don't know what ding you mean. The above answers the question of how you write your quoted code with Prototype. Whether it does what you want it to do is another question entirely. :-)

Comment: Noticed it was an issue with Prototype 1.6+IE9. Upgrading to 1.7 and handling the event as per your answer worked perfectly.